# how to add fixed step knob in GUI using processing?

Tags: arduino, processing

I'm developing a GUI for my Arduino Mega 2560 board. I need a fixed step knob with 4 values. I've used control P5 library but the knob range in that is continuous.

Suggest me how to get fixed step knob with code. Whenever i press knob with my mouse near the tick mark on knob it should change to that value
BTW I've no idea of java programming just started learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [setting the number of tickmarks](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/reference/controlP5/Knob.html#setNumberOfTickMarks-int-) to 3

Here's the tweaked **Examples > Contributed Libraries > ControlP5 > controllers > ControlP5knob** example:

```java
/**
* ControlP5 Knob
*
*
* find a list of public methods available for the Knob Controller
* at the bottom of this sketch.
*
* by Andreas Schlegel, 2012
* www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlp5
*
*/

import controlP5.*;


ControlP5 cp5;

int myColorBackground = color(0,0,0);
int knobValue = 100;

Knob myKnobA;
Knob myKnobB;

void setup() {
  size(700,400);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
  
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  
  myKnobA = cp5.addKnob("knob")
               .setRange(0,255)
               .setValue(50)
               .setPosition(100,70)
               .setRadius(50)
               .setDragDirection(Knob.VERTICAL)
               ;
                     
  myKnobB = cp5.addKnob("knobValue")
               .setRange(0,255)
               .setValue(220)
               .setPosition(100,210)
               .setRadius(50)
               .setNumberOfTickMarks(3)
               .setTickMarkLength(4)
               .snapToTickMarks(true)
               .setColorForeground(color(255))
               .setColorBackground(color(0, 160, 100))
               .setColorActive(color(255,255,0))
               .setDragDirection(Knob.HORIZONTAL)
               ;
}

void draw() {
  background(myColorBackground);
  fill(knobValue);
  rect(0,height/2,width,height/2);
  fill(0,100);
  rect(80,40,140,320);
}


void knob(int theValue) {
  myColorBackground = color(theValue);
  println("a knob event. setting background to "+theValue);
}


void keyPressed() {
  switch(key) {
    case('1'):myKnobA.setValue(180);break;
    case('2'):myKnobB.setConstrained(false).hideTickMarks().snapToTickMarks(false);break;
    case('3'):myKnobA.shuffle();myKnobB.shuffle();break;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: thanks. it worked.